# Using MediaRecorder multiple times

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I'm trying to use Media Recorder to record audio. I have it working so that I am able to record and play back. The only problem is that I am not able to record a second time the program crashes. I have a separate  method to reset the MediaRecorder, but wherever I place it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's your problem. If you want to record media & save after that play file which has just recorded, you can using MediaRecorder to record and MediaPlayer to play but I am not recommend.

- The first. You have to ensure your file is recorded. (I recommend you save as .mp3 file)
  Looking for this project. It will be useful.
  [Go LameMP3 tutorial](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI)
- The second. Playing mp3 file is not difficult. You can try this code:
  [Play mp3 file in SDCARD](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/play-mp3-in-sd-card-using-androids.html)